# Replace element by another xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following part of my xml:

```
<root>
    <notesbydate>
        <notedate date="1996-12-06T00:00:00">
            <note>
                <notedate>asdasd</notedate>
            </note>
        </notedate>
        <notedate date="1996-12-06T00:00:00">
            <note>
                <notedate>asdasd</notedate>
            </note>
        </notedate>
    </notesbydate>
</root>
```

The thing I want to do Is to replace the notesbydate element with another element called ndates. I have tried this:

```
 XElement test = xDoc.Element("notesbydate");
            test.ReplaceWith(
                new XElement("NewChild")
            );
```

But I only get an error when doing this.. Anyone who can explain what should do?

I get this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in xmlParser.exe
>       Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @RussClarke: Check my updated question

Comment: @tolanj: Yeah, It is an XDocument. What do u mean? I just want to replace/change name of the notesbydate to ndates.

Comment: @tolanj: What do u mean?

Comment: Replacing an element will replace all its children unless you add the children to your new element

Comment: @tolanj: And how do I add the children to the new element? Can u show me a example?

Comment: @tolanj there is [`Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method.

Comment: Indeed, though not showing up in nav bar on msn on XDocument (does on XContainer), please ignore, i will remove my comments

Comment: If you genuinely just mean to rename xDoc.Element("notesbydate").Name="newName" ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as it's below the root element:

```
XElement test = xDoc.Root.Element("notesbydate");
test.ReplaceWith(
                    new XElement("NewChild")
                );
```

Alternatively you can use

```
XElement test = xDoc.Element("root").Element("notesbydate");
```

and to rename the element:

```
test.Name = "NewChild";
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help me. I just want to replace/rename the element, and keep It's childs. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Bryan: ah ok. I thought your problem was not accessing the element. To only rename you can set the Name property. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: AH! So easy haha. Thank you so much and sorry for my blurry question.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to write in function what to put instead of element. See the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<root>
                        <notesbydate>
                           <notedate date=""1996 - 12 - 06T00: 00:00"">
                                  <note>
                                       <notedate> asdasd </notedate>
                                  </note>
                                 </notedate>
                              <notedate date = ""1996-12-06T00:00:00"">
                                   <note>
                                        <notedate> asdasd </notedate>
                                   </note>
                                </notedate>
                              </notesbydate>
                       </root>";

        var xDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
        XElement test = xDoc.Element("notesbydate");
        xDoc.Element("notesbydate").Name = "YourNewName";           
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302711(v=vs.110).aspx) is more details

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help me. I just want to replace/rename the element, and keep It's childs. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Then you should make your question more precise.